# How do I make a function loop inside itself? Raspberry Pi 4 and Python

Tags: python

I want a function to loop in itself.

this is inside a `while true`

```
def DRPLoop(MotorGPIO, DRPInput):
                gpio.output(MotorGPIO, GPIO.HIGH)
                if DRPInput == False:
                        time.sleep(60)
                        gpio.output(MotorGPIO, GPIO.LOW)
                        time.sleep(60)
                        #loop DRPLoop()
                else if DRPInput == True:
                        gpio.output(MotorGPIO, GPIO.HIGH)
                        #loop DRPLoop()
```

Comment: Without more context (and preferably some [mcve]), your question is quite unclear...

Comment: consider searching information about *`recursion`*

Comment: @Tomerikoo Unbounded recursion is a bad idea; infinite recursion is worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop. While you *could* call the function recursively, you'll eventually run out of stack space, as Python is not optimized to handle unbounded recursion. A loop does not have that problem.

```
def DRPLoop(MotorGPIO, DRPInput):
    while True:
        gpio.output(MotorGPIO, GPIO.HIGH)
        if not DRPInput:
            time.sleep(60)
            gpio.output(MotorGPIO, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(60)
        else:
            gpio.output(MotorGPIO, GPIO.HIGH)
```

Note however, that `DRPInput` never changes inside the function. You might want the loop to be what *calls* `DRPLoop` instead in the first place.